# Let $a$ be an integer such that all real roots of the polynomial $2x^5+5x^4+10x^3+10x^2+10x+10$ lie in the interval $(a,a+1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, roots, rolles-theorem

We need to find what $a$ is. Can I not solve this using the mean value theorem in the interval $(a,a+1)$?

I tried for a $c\in(a,a+1)$

$$f(c)=\int_a^{a+1}f(x)dx$$
but since all the roots lie in $(a,a+1), f(c)=0$
We could just integrate $f(x)$ and try different values of $a$ unless the equation is satisfied, but apparently this doesn't work.Why?

Comment: Could you elaborate how all the roots lie in $(a, a+1)$ implies $f(c) = 0$?

Comment: @VTand since $c\in(a,a+1)$ and $f(x)$ has all real roots in that interval can't we find a $c$ such that $f(c)=0$?

Comment: Have you attempted to draw the graphical representation of $y=2x^5+5x^4+...$ in order to have an idea of the value of $a$ ?

Comment: Using the characterisation $f(c)=\int_a^{a+1}...$ is a little "overkill" IMHO...

Comment: @JeanMarie Yeah, I did analyse it's derivative and found that the function is strictly increasing and used the intermediate value to "locate" the root but I was wondering why this doesn't work.

Comment: @JeanMarie well, this was the thing that popped in my mind furst, figuring out that the derivative was positive took me a bit too long

Comment: @ParthShresth The value $c$ is already fixed when you define $f(c) = \int_a^{a+1} f(x) \: dx$ by MVT.

Comment: What can you say about the sign of your function from one end of the interval to the other, and how can you use this to solve your problem?

Comment: @MarkBennet the signs of the function at the ends of the interval must be opposite, which suggest that $f(a)f(a+1)<0$ but that doesnt seem to help

Comment: Well, on how many distinct intervals between successive integers can the function change sign?

Comment: @MarkBennet It should be atleast one as the function has an odd leading power but how should I proceed

Comment: Using the Cauchy bound for polynomial roots, you can see that any root must be on the interval $(-6, -\frac 16)$. Looking for the roots of the derivative in the same way, you can narrow it down to the interval $-4, -\frac 14)$. This does not leave many possible values for $a$.

Comment: Please give the full problem statement in the body of your Question,  not relying on the title for that purpose.   The jump from title to body and the title's relative brevity can make reading difficult.

Comment: @PierreCarre I didn't know a cauchy bound was. I googled it and found out that it gives only an upper bound, do you mind elaborating how did you find a lower bound for the roots?

Comment: But count the roots - how many intervals can have a change of sign? Then it is just a search for an interval, and there are various ways reducing the search space.

Comment: [`plot 2x^5+5x^4+10x^3+10x^2+10x+10`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+2x%5E5%2B5x%5E4%2B10x%5E3%2B10x%5E2%2B10x%2B10) in Wolfram Alpha shows you what $a$ must be, and you can verify it easily by evaluating $f(a)$ and $f(a+1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f$ be the polynomial. Since $f$'s degree is odd, there is at least one root. This combined with the fact that the polynomial is strictly increasing, gives you that there is exactly one root. Now, we evaluate $f$ for some easy negative numbers (clearly the roots must be negative):
$$f(-1)=3\text{ and }f(-2)=-34.$$
Therefore, the root(s) lies in $(-2,-1)$.